# Sum of Consecutive Integers is equal to a given number

Tags: number-theory

### consecutive sum

Given an integer N, you have to find the number of ways you can express N as sum of consecutive integers. You have to use at least two integers.

For example, N = 15 has three solutions, (1+2+3+4+5), (4+5+6), (7+8).

Comment: I think I remember that it is the number of odd divisors greater than 1.

Comment: See this post too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207077/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-consecutive-integers

Comment: @turkeyhundt, yes your solution is correct, I know the solution but How can I prove? what is the theory behind it?